# Using information from the previous step in generators?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, methods, generator

I have a generator which tries to mimic realtime. This generator makes sure that the user has no access to the future but only to current time.

To simplify my case i use this generator

```
def generator(n):
    for x in range(n):
        yield [[x],[x+3]]
```

if run for `n = 5` the generator returns:

```
[[0], [3]]
[[1], [4]]
[[2], [5]]
[[3], [6]]
[[4], [7]]
```

I want to be able to combine the elements of each generator iteration with the elements of previous generator iteration to compute `sum()` of inner lists

case 1:

```
sum([0]), sum([3])
```

case 2:

```
sum([0,1]), sum([3,4])
```

case 3:

```
sum([0,1,2]), sum([3,4,5])
```

...

case LAST

```
sum([0,1,2,3,4]), sum([3,4,5,6,7])
```

I don't see how this can be achieved by using:

```
for x in generator(5):
    do sum operation
```

the values that I will use in the `for` loop will be gone for the next iteration.

Please do not focus on the numbers and the results, but mainly on the logic and algorithm behind a possible solution. In this case for me it is important to be able to preserve the situation where access to future data is not allowed, only data from the past can be used for calculations, however the data that I consider from the past is already gone when the for iteration is ended!

Any solution? Suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you store the previously processed data?

Comment: @dm03514 yes it is allowed to store the previous iterations of the generator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l1, l2 = [], []
for x1, x2 in generator(5):
    l1.extend(x1)
    l2.extend(x2)
    print sum(l1), sum(l2)
```

Seems pretty straightforward. It's not like the generator can force you to forget what it gave you. If the operation you want to do is something as simple as `sum`, you don't even need to keep all the old data, just its sum.

```
sum1 = sum2 = 0
for x1, x2 in generator(5)
    sum1 += x1[0]
    sum2 += x2[0]
```

If the number of lists you need is dynamic, that's easy to handle:

```
lists = [[] for _ in xrange(numberoflists)]
for subtuple in generator(5):
    for element, sublist in zip(subtuple, lists):
        sublist.extend(element)
    do_whatever_with(map(sum, lists))
```

Comment: Looks like we both took nearly the exact same approach. Unpacking the values from the generator makes a lot of sense. Much easier to read.

Comment: the first code snipped serves better my case. How can I handle the situation where the number of lists in the beginning: `l1`, `l2` has to be defined dynamically, then also the number of `l1.extend(x1)` operations has to be dynamic...

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne: See expanded answer.

Comment: maybe you meant `range(numberoflists)` instead of only `numberoflists` or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood this correctly, but are you trying to do something like this?

```
>>> tmp = [[],[]]
>>> for x in generator(5):
        tmp[0] += x[0]
        tmp[1] += x[1]
        print sum(tmp[0]),sum(tmp[1])


0, 3
1, 7
3, 12
6, 18
10, 25
>>> tmp
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Or if you don't want to save the entire list:

```
>>> tmp = [0,0]
>>> for x in generator(5):
        tmp[0] += x[0][0]
        tmp[1] += x[1][0]
        print tmp[0],tmp[1]


0, 3
1, 7
3, 12
6, 18
10, 25
```